# Limit of a function with 2 variables

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I am given this function: $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{xy^3}{x^2+y^4} & \text{ for } (x,y)\not=(0,0)\\ 0 & \text{ for } (x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$ and I have to check if it is continuous in $(0,0)$. Therefore I want to calculate $\lim \limits_{(x,y) \rightarrow 0}{\frac{xy^3}{x^2+y^4}}$.

I already tried substituting and polar coordinates but did not come to a solution yet.

Can someone give a few possibilities to calculate a limit of a function with multiple variables. Which is the best one to try first? I found that polarcoordinates often works very well.

There has already been a question concerning this function and it's partial derivates and if it's differentiable. You may find that one here:   [determine whether $f(x, y) = \frac{xy^3}{x^2 + y^4}$ is differentiable at $(0, 0)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/967372/determine-whether-fx-y-fracxy3x2-y4-is-differentiable-at-0-0)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach $(0,0)$ from a few different paths, and you will find that it appears the limit is in fact $0$. To prove this is the case, you can use the Squeeze Theorem.

We have that 
\begin{align*}
\bigg|\frac{xy^{3}}{x^{2} + y^{4}} - 0 \bigg| &\leq \bigg|\frac{xy^{3}}{2xy^{2}}\bigg| && \text{using the inequality } 2ab \leq a^{2} + b^{2}
\end{align*}
and from here it should be easy to find a bounding function and show that its limit is indeed $0$, which implies by the Squeeze Theorem that the limit of $f$ as $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$ is $0$ as well.

Comment: That was actually pretty easy, I think I should write myself a list of usefull inequations... Thank you!

Comment: @user254331 I didn't show the direct usage of the Squeeze Theorem, but I presume you have learned it and understand how it is used here? If not I can add to my answer. And you are welcome.

Comment: @user254331 And in general, I always have found that that particular inequality, along with adding to the numerator to allow the denominator to cancel out are the most useful strategies when attempting to apply the Squeeze Theorem to a multivariable limit.

Comment: Yes I do and showing $\begin{align*}
\bigg|\frac{xy^{3}}{x^{2} + y^{4}} - 0 \bigg| &\leq \bigg|\frac{xy^{3}}{2xy^{2}}\bigg| =\bigg| \frac{y}{2}\bigg| \rightarrow 0\end{align*}$ would already be enough for the exam. I just missed out some skills which most students learned at school and sometimes I just don't "see" those kind of things (therefore I prefer (linear) algebra). Fortunaly these kinds of calculations are not the main focus of the exam. Most of the exercises are to proof something more generalized.

Comment: @user254331 Appreciated, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}{\frac{xy^3}{x^2+y^4}}$$
Using polar coordinates, we have
$$\lim\limits_{r\to 0^+}{\frac{r^4\cos\phi \sin^3\phi}{r^2\cos^2\phi+r^4\sin^4\phi}}$$
$$=\lim\limits_{r\to 0^+}{\frac{\cos\phi \sin^3\phi}{\frac{\cos^2\phi}{r^2}+\sin^4\phi}}$$
$$={\frac{\cos\phi \sin^3\phi}{\lim\limits_{r\to 0^+}\frac{\cos^2\phi}{r^2}+\sin^4\phi}}$$
$$={\frac{\cos\phi \sin^3\phi}{\cos^2\phi\lim\limits_{r\to 0^+}\frac{1}{r^2}+\sin^4\phi}}$$
Note that
$$\lim\limits_{r\to 0^+}\frac{1}{r^2}=\infty$$
Therefore
$${\frac{\cos\phi \sin^3\phi}{\cos^2\phi\lim\limits_{r\to 0^+}\frac{1}{r^2}+\sin^4\phi}}=0$$
And
$$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}{\frac{xy^3}{x^2+y^4}}=0$$

Comment: Thank you, even though I prefer Godzillas solution, this seems like a good approach if you can't find a matching inequality.

Comment: Such a use of polar coordinates proves only convergence to 0 along lines passing through origin. We need a uniform bound for the angle $\phi$ in order for this to work